# Using for_each to call a print function from a list of object

Tags: c++, list

I need to use a for_each function to call the print function of each object in the list of objects `shapeList`.  When I put function `output` as the final parameter of `for_each`, I get a "cannot determine which instance of overloaded function "output" is intended.

```
void output(Point* point)
{
    point->print();
}
```

This is my output function for `for_each`

```
for_each(shapeList.begin(), shapeList.end(), output);
```

The for_each statement

I have looked at other solutions that involve using binds and lambdas, but this is a class assignment and I cannot use those methods.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

#define sz 12

using namespace std;

class Point
{
private:
    int x, y;
public:
    Point() { }
    Point(int a, int b)
        :x(a), y(b) { }
    // print function is pure virtual and that makes class Point an abstract class
    // a pure virtual function can have prototype only without definition
    // an abstract class can't be instantiated
    // its derived class must override this function in order to be a real class
    virtual void print() const = 0;
};

void Point::print() const
{
    cout << "\nPoint: ( "
         << x
         << " , "
         << y
         << " )";
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class Circle : public Point
{
private:
    int radius;
public:
    Circle() : Point() { }
    Circle(int a, int b, int c)
        :Point(a, b), radius(c) { }

    virtual void print() const;
};

void Circle::print() const
{
    cout << "\nCenter of the Circle is at:  ";
    Point::print();
    cout << "\nRadius of the Circle is: "
         << radius;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class Cylinder : public Circle
{
private:
    int height;
    char color[sz];
public:
    Cylinder() { }
    Cylinder(int a, int b, int r, int h, char clr[])
    :   Circle(a, b, r), height(h)
    { strcpy(color, clr); }

    virtual void print() const;
};

void Cylinder::print() const
{
    Circle::print();

    cout << "\nHeight of Cylinder is: "
         << height
         << "\nColor of Cylinder is: "
         << color
         << endl;
}

void load_list(list<Point*>&, char*); // 
void output(Point*&);

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main()
{
    char clr[10];

    list<Point*> shapeList;////

    load_list(shapeList, clr);

    for_each(shapeList.begin(), shapeList.end(), output);

    return 0;
}

void load_list(list<Point*>& ptList, char *ch)
{
    char type;
    int x, y, r, h;

    ifstream infile("shapes.txt");
    if (!infile)
    {
        cout << "\nCan not open input file.";
        exit(1);
    }

    infile >> type;

    while (infile)
    {
        if (type == 'c')
        {
            infile >> x >> y >> r;
            ptList.push_back(new Circle(x,y,r));
        }
        else if (type = 'l')
        {
            infile >> x >> y >> r >> h >> ch;
            ptList.push_back(new Cylinder(x, y, r, h, ch));
        }
        infile >> type;
    }
}

void output(Point* point)
{
    point->print();
}
```

Comment: Does the compiler list the overloads it sees?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It just gives the the error at compile time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare the function to take a pointer by reference(?) And the implementation takes a pointer.

Comment: Well don't I feel stupid.  That was it. Thank you very much